# Linear equations question unique/infinite/no solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For what value(s) of $k$, if any, will the system have no solution, a unique solution, and infinitely many solutions? (Enter your answers as a comma-separated list. If an answer does not exist, enter DNE.)

$$kx  +  3y  =  4$$
$$3x  −  9y  =  −12$$

I just want to check my answer for infinitely many and a unique solution
Thanks!

Comment: See almost same question here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469484/for-what-values-of-k-will-the-system-have-muliple-solutions