# For what values of $k$ will the system have multiple solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

For what value(s) of $k$, if any, will the system have a) no solutions b) a unique solution c) infinitely many solutions?

$$kx + 2y = 3$$
$$2x - 4y = -6$$

I know how to get the answer to (c), I got when $k = -1$.

I have no clue for the other two problems.